# How to replace certain words without replacing the whitespace before it in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace certain words in javascript but it has to be the exact word. For example, if the word is run then running shouldn't be matched.

The current regex expression replaces the whitespace in front of the words. How can I make it find all cases of the exact word (Even in the beginning of the sentence) without replacing the spaces, but ignoring commmas, question marks, etc.? Thanks!

```
new RegExp('([^a-zA-Z0-9_-]|^)' + wa + '(?![a-zA-Z0-9_-])'
```

Comment: Use `\b` to match word boundaries w/o consuming a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [word boundary(`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to assert the word boundary.

```
new RegExp('\\b' + wa + '\\b')
```

---

Or replace with [captured group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) value.

```
string.replace(new RegExp('([^a-zA-Z0-9_-]|^)' + wa + '(?![a-zA-Z0-9_-])'), '$1')
```